# Entity Framework Core - Pomelo Migration / Scaffolding

Tags: c#, mysql, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm looking for some help with using Pomelo. I'm using this in a C# enviroment and would like it to make changes when my script starts. For example, when I add a new table to my context, I would like this to be made when my server restarts. I'm getting an error when enabling the migrations method and ensurecreated is only when it first starts with no database.

I'm calling this when the server starts;

```
using (var context = new Context())
{
   context.Database.EnsureCreated();
   context.Database.Migrate();
}
```

I've tried using these individually but to no success. When using the migrate method, it's saying that the table isn't found. It's only creating the migration table and no others.

Comment: Are you using `EF core` migrations? If you are then you need to use only `context.Database.Migrate()`. Otherwise you need to use only `context.Database.EnsureCreated();`

Comment: Yes I am. When using just migrate it’s not creating my tables and databases.

Comment: @Moretti what error are you getting?